# Nested attributes undefined user_comments_path error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I'm trying to follow Ryan Bates polymorphic models tutorial (Rails 3), to implement comments in my photo model. I'm having trouble when trying to create a new comment for photos since I'm in Rails 4 and I have to deal with :comment strong parameters.

#### Error: undefined method `user_comments_path' for #<#:0x00000107c8a200>

I have nested resources

```
  #Nesting Resources
  resources :users do
    resources :photos do
      resources :comments
      resources :tags
    end
  end
```

So the route should be /users/friendly-id/photos/friendly-id/comments, but it's getting badly constructed, I have `<%= form_for [@user, @commentable, @comment] do |f| %>` in my form.

Photo Controller

```
#create
    def show
        @photo = Photo.friendly.find(params[:id])
        @user = @photo.user
        @tag = Tag.new
        @tag.photo_id = @photo.id
        @category = Category.all
        @commentable = @photo
        @comments = @commentable.comments
        @comment = Comment.new
        @zone = Zone.all
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html #show.html.erb
            format.json {render json: @photo}
        end
    end
```

**Form**

```
<%= form_for [@user, @commentable, @comment] do |f| %>
  <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Please correct the following errors.</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

**Comments controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_commentable

  def index
    @comments = @commentable.comments
  end


  def new
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new
  end

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment created."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

private

  def load_commentable
    resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]
    @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
  end

  def comment_params 
    require(:comment).permit(:photo_id, :user_id, :content)
  end


  ###Error 2: When I put friendly.id instead of only id in `load_commentable` method I get a Forbidden Attribute error.
end
```

Please someone help! Thank you

Comment: can you gist the full error, with backtrace?

Comment: @sevenseacat But it's show because the #new comment form goes in the Photo show method (Comments below each photo)

Comment: In this gist: https://gist.github.com/isasi88/725dceddf1ddd58227af